# Stability conditions for the Luttinger liquid

Tags: tomonaga-luttinger-liquid

I came across an interesting question and was not able to find an answer in the internet, so let's see whether someone of you can help. I was working on a problem using the bosonization method and thereby I saw the formula for the spin velocity in the Luttinger liquid:

$u_{\sigma} = v_F\sqrt{1 - \tilde{g}^2_1 }$

Here, $v_F$ is the Fermi velocity and $\tilde{g_1}$ is some (scaled) backscattering matrix element. From a mathematical point of view, if $\tilde{g}_1>1$, this is not a meaningful expression. My question is: what is the physics behind this or what does it physically mean if $\tilde{g}_1>1$.

Thanks,

Niels